Leaving tenure track position
I'm a relatively new tenure-track professor considering leaving my academic institution for another academic institution or a non-academic job in the not-too-distant future.
I have two questions:

When to Inform Colleagues: If I decide to leave, when should I tell my colleagues, both in my department and outside? I want to avoid any backlash but also give enough notice.

General Advice: Do you have any tips or suggestions on how to handle this?


Any insights or experiences would be very helpful. Thank you!

Also related: I want to leave my tenure track position before fall. I have great prospects but no new position "locked up": when should I break the news?

Welcome to Academia.SE. Your question is so vague we can't really help you -- what part of the world are you in? What type of institution? Why (generally) do you want to leave? Will you resign before or after you have another job lined up? As it is, we can't really add anything to the linked posts, so your question has been closed. However, if you want to [edit] your question to provide more details, we may find that there is a distinct question here. Good luck.
